# Implementation of compiler-generated moves

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

How are the implicitly compiler-generated move constructors and move assigment operator implemented by the compiler?

Does the compiler use the copy-and-swap idiom with a unified `operator=` (with its strong exception-safety guarantee), or does it implement a member-wise move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the compiler use the copy-and-swap idiom with a unified operator= (with its strong exception-safety guarantee), or does it implement a member-wise move?

Per Paragraph 12.8/15 of the C++11 Standard:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a **memberwise copy/move of its bases and members**. [...]

Moreover, per Paragraph 12.8/28:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class X performs **memberwise copy-
>   /move assignment of its subobjects**. [...]

Answer (score 4):

It's a memberwise move, just as the implicitly-defined copy operations do a memberwise copy. See 12.8 [class.copy] paragraphs 15 and 25.

Copy-and-swap wouldn't be possible for a non-copyable type or non-swappable type, you don't want the move operations to depend on another special member or a `swap` member that might not exist or might not work as required.